# What is the difference between /lib and /usr/lib and /var/lib?

Tags: directory-structure

What is the difference between `/lib` and `/usr/lib` and `/var/lib`? Some of the files are symbolic links that "duplicate" content of other directories.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Someone else can probably explain this with much more detail and historical reference but the short answer:

### [/lib](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s09.html)

is a place for the essential standard libraries.  Think of libraries required for your system to run.  If something in `/bin` or `/sbin` needs a library that library is likely in `/lib`.

### [/usr/lib](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s06.html)

the `/usr` directory in general is as it sounds, a user based directory.  Here you will find things used by the users on the system.  So if you install an application that needs libraries they might go to `/usr/lib`.  If a binary in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin` needs a library it will likely be in `/usr/lib`.

### [/var/lib](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s08.html)

the `/var` directory is the writable counterpart to the `/usr` directory which is often required to be read-only.  So `/var/lib` would have a similar purpose as `/usr/lib` but with the ability to write to them.

Comment: Just to improve a bit - it all comes from Filesystem Hierarchy Standard. The definition is a bit old-ish now but still offers interesting insight. https://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html

Comment: This answer is at least 15 years late, yeah, "historically" it's correct but Linux distros haven't had /bin /sbin and /lib for many years now and all three are linked to the appropriate /usr directories. And `/var/lib` normally holds transcient data, you may as well delete completely and the system won't be affected. Lastly it's probably the 150th time this question has been asked. Dunno why people jump to answer it again and again.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Sorry, but there's a whole lot of inaccuracies in your comment. "15 years" is way off, Fedora made the move to /usr [in 2012](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove) and it certainly wasn't the last major distro to do so (if not the first). `/var/lib` is definitely not for transient data, at least not on most distros. Deleting it is going to have disastrous consequences on a typical system (destroying the yumdb/rpmdb and breaking the package manager with no way to repair it, nuking the default storage location of various SQL databases or VMs with precious data, etc.)

Comment: noteworthy: "as it *sounds*, a user based directory" - `usr` sounds like "user", but it actually stands for Unix System Resources

Comment: If you destroy your RPM/APT databases your system will **not** stop functioning but it will make managing packages quite an issue. And various databases are again not something the system depends on. I don't know a single file or directory under `/var` without which the system will fail to boot normally - that was what I meant by "transient". And even 15 years ago there was no longer a clear distinction between /bin|/sbin|/lib and /usr directories. So, you could be a little bit more reserved and humble about "inaccuracies" in my comment.

Comment: 40 years ago, right, /bin /sbin /lib were the ones the system couldn't boot without but this distinction has **long** been lost in the world of Linux distros. Maybe there UNIX/POSIX compatible OSes out there which still stick to this rule but I'm not aware of them. I've certainly never used OpenBSD/NetBSD and last used FreeBSD over a decade ago. Then there's QNX, AIX, Solaris and other even more obscure UNIX distros.

Comment: @kubi That smells of Folk Etymology or Convenient Backronym to me; it's not even a good description of its role. Wikipedia cites [these notes from Dennis Ritchie](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/notes.html) describing the origin as "a directory '/usr' which contains all user's directories, and which is stored on a relatively large, but slow moving head disk".

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Quite a few services depend on `/var/run` for pid files or other data. This a link to `../run` but that doesn't help if you cannot find the link to follow it. I would consider a rebooted system broken if it remote and `sshd` could not start because `/var` disappeared.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov As a specific example, on CentOS 7 `sssd` will put it's pid in `/var/run/sssd.pid`. The service will not start if `/var/run` is missing. System is up but nobody can authenticate.

Comment: @doneal Maybe it's more accurate to say that a system can boot up even with all the *files* in `/var/` missing. I will agree that losing the directory structure will cause issues with software that expect those dirs to be there.

Comment: @doneal24 We talked about files, right? Not directories. So let's assume at least predefined `/var` directories are there (`lib`, `log`, `run` and `tmp` - nothing else is required actually). And here you're wrong again:`/var/run` is a symlink to `/run` which is populated at boot time. Again, everything under `/var` is transient whether you want it or not, including RPM/APT databases (which are dynamically populated and can be recreated in case they are accidentally or intentionally lost/deleted - it's gonna be painful but it's totally possible). There's  0 common between `/usr/lib`&`/var/lib`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Copying from your earlier comment, `I don't know a single file or directory under /var without which the system will fail to boot normally`. We are talking about both files and directories. Also, if `/var` is empty, how do you create `/var/run/sssd.pid`. The symlink doesn't exist because `/var` is empty. Doesn't matter that `/run` is dynamically created.

Comment: We started talking **specifically about files**, now you are talking about directories. How nice of you. Sorry, I don't argue with *<possibly bad words redacted>*.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov If you don't want to discuss/defend your earlier blanket statement, that's fine. Devolving into name calling is beneath the standards of this group.

Comment: @IMSoP, you are in fact correct that this was a retronym.

Answer (score 13):

Files in `/lib` and `/usr/lib` are supposed to be mostly read only and identical between systems.  (If it was a container image, they could be fully read only and shared between systems; on a stand alone system, they need to be writable to install updates.)

Files in `/var` are specific to the local system and frequently contain data that is generated by system operation.

Typically distribution versions of templates for config files can be found in `/usr/lib` and can be used to create localized versions of config files in `/etc` or possibly `/var`.

I'm not sure why there would be duplicate files between `/lib` and `/usr/lib`, more likely they are symlinks and not duplicates.  (There are no such files on my current system, and only one symlink.)

Historically directories like `/usr/lib` `/usr/bin` were actually created because `/usr` was on a separate disk and things were put there because `/bin` and `/lib` were on the root disk which was too small to hold everything, and what was left on the root disk were things critical to boot far enough to mount `/usr`.  Of course, this concept is obsolete, and there is a movement to merge them.

Comment: I've used systems that had /bin -> /usr/bin. Why not /lib -> /usr/lib?

Comment: That is happening too probably.

Comment: It's happening, but slowly. Mostly because distribution maintainers tend not to throw something away that still works, the added benefit to moving everything to `/usr/lib` is debatable at best, there may still be large networks where `/usr` is mounted from a network share, and most importantly manually going through up to thousands of packages to see if they might cause edge case issues with the `/lib` -> `/usr/lib` move is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: From what I've read the `/bin` -> `/usr/bin` move has been applied and backed out a few times for exactly that reason too.

Comment: Ubuntu since 19.10 makes `/bin`, `/lib`, `/lib64` etc. all symlinks to those in `/usr`. Debian does so since Buster. It's a universal move now that we rarely have separate mounts for `/` and `/usr`.

Comment: I don't think it is Ubuntu 19.10 that does this so much as a specific package that might be installed by default in Ubuntu 19.10, because I have Ubuntu 20 systems that don't have them merged.  Like I said, it has been applied and backed out several times.